# Race condition in program

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to threading. So, I just created 4 dedicated threads (rather using Tasks) one after other, and giving them something to work. But, It made me a doubt about race condition in startProcessing function where I am simply storing the value on currentIndex to a local variable within lock. However, I ran it so many times, but could not satisfy that there is no race issue or anything else.

Please help me to clear this thing.

```
class Program
{

    private static object syncLock = new object();
    int num = 0;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.num = 1000;
        p.callThreadCreation();

        while (p.num > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }

    public void callThreadCreation()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            string name = "T" + i;
            Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => startProcessing()));
            T.Name = name;
            T.Start();
        }

    }

    **private void startProcessing()
    {
        while (num > 0)
        {
            int tempIndex;
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                tempIndex = currentIndex;
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref num);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);
            print(tempIndex);  
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }**

    private void print(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: Reading from `int` variable is atomic. There is no need to put lock around it alone.

Comment: Your startProcessing method doesn't look thread-safe to me.  The num variable may cause a race condition while it's being tested in the while loop.

Comment: You should be avoiding shared stated (and particularly shared mutable state) at all costs.  When you absolutely do need to use it, use tools *specifically* designed to be used from multiple threads.  This type of very low level and low-lock threading is *very* hard to get right.  You shouldn't be starting here at all.  Use higher level constructs such as `Parallel.For` to do work in parallel such that none of the code you're writing is ever sharing data between threads.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `startProcessing` method. Imagine all four threads arrive at the `while` check together. Since the loop check isn't synchronized, all four might enter the loop when `num` is, say, 2.

1. First thread arrives at `while` check. Sees num > 0. Enters loop. Releases context.
2. Second thread  arrives at `while` check. Num is still 2, thus > 0.
3. Repeat for third and fourth threads.
4. Now you're in the race condition. All four threads are inside the loop body and unprotected by the `while` check. The Decrement operations will all be nicely atomic and synchronized, but you'll still be at -2 when the four operations complete. You have the > 0 test, but it's performed outside the lock. Thus, your `currentIndex` might be incremented more than 1000 times - as much as 1003 times, I think, one extra increment for each extra thread that might have entered the loop unnecessarily.

Comment: Specifically [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is needed for read access on `num` like at the `while` check.

Comment: what should be the fix to this problem. I want to call print(int x) function, for    upto the value of num? print(int x) is a big method which invokes a web service function in actual. How should I restructure this?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your original program slightly (moved around `Thread.Sleep`s and `Console.WriteLine()`s, to make the race condition easier to detect.  Also, I changed the top count to 11, not a multiple of 4 (the number of threads that you spawn).  Theoretically, this doesn't change the behavior at all, just how *likely* it is to occur.

```
class Program
{
    private static object syncLock = new object();
    int num = 0;
    // make static so we can read in Main()
    static int currentIndex = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.num = 11;
        p.callThreadCreation();

        while (p.num > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All done {0}", currentIndex);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public void callThreadCreation()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            string name = "T" + i;
            Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => startProcessing()));
            T.Name = name;
            T.Start();
        }
    }

    private void startProcessing()
    {
        while (num > 0)
        {
            int tempIndex;
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                tempIndex = currentIndex;
            }

            // putting this in front of the increment/decrement operations makes the race condition more likely
            print(tempIndex);
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref num);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void print(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

If you try this program, eventually you should see the program output 12 at the end.  Below is the program I came up with to fix the race condition.  I admit it's not the most elegant, but in such a simple example it probably doesn't need to be so elegant.

```
class Program
{
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();
    private int num = 0;
    private static int currentIndex = 0;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.num = 11;

        // just return the threads, so we can join
        var threadList = p.callThreadCreation();

        // don't need Thread.Sleep() here
        //while (p.num > 0)
        //{
        //    Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //}
        foreach (var t in threadList) { t.Join(); }

        Console.WriteLine("All done {0}", currentIndex);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Thread> callThreadCreation()
    {
        var threadList = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            // this is easier to read for me
            var T = new Thread(startProcessing)
            {
                Name = "T" + i
            };

            // just return the threads, so we can join
            threadList.Add(T);
            T.Start();
        }

        // just return the threads, so we can join
        return threadList;
    }

    private void startProcessing()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int tempIndex;
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                // I'm not sure what the point of this line is... sometimes "tempIndex" will
                // be the same between two threads, but this just seems like a progress report
                // for the person watching the program so I didn't fix this.
                tempIndex = currentIndex;
                num--;
                if (num < 0) break;
            }

            print(tempIndex);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void print(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

This one should be free of a race condition.  The idea is that the `increment` operation on the value of contention (`num`) is inside of the same lock as what is checking the value `num` for completion.  In your example, this isn't true, so there could be a context switch at an inopportune time to make `num` change more times than you want.  This is also the idea behind why I changed where `Console.WriteLine()` happens: to increase this chance of an inopportune context switch.